# Can we call the received data(after combination) as `message`?

Tags: switch

In the `message` transmission, the `message` A is a Word document(20M).

When A transfer, it will be divide to many packets, every package added a header for marking as source address and destination address.

In the accept end, it will cut off the packet header, and group them as a whole Word document(20M).

in there, can we call the received data as `message`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the message transmission, the message A is a Word document (20M).

Since you used the tag [switch](/questions/tagged/switch) you are referring to layer 2. In [layer 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) the frame is the "message".

> When A transfer, it will be divide to many packets, every package added a header for marking as source address and destination address.

Not at layer 2.

- [Data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)

  > "The data link layer is concerned with local delivery of frames between nodes on the same level of the network. **Data-link frames, as these protocol data units are called, do not cross the boundaries of a local network**. Inter-network **routing and global addressing are higher-layer functions**, allowing data-link protocols to focus on local delivery, addressing, and media arbitration. This way, the data link layer is analogous to a neighborhood traffic cop; it endeavors to arbitrate between parties contending for access to a medium, without concern for their ultimate destination.".

> In the accept end, it will cut off the packet header, and group them as a whole Word document (20M). In there, can we call the received data as message?

A 20 megabyte file would use [layer 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer#Analysis) to assemble the segments into a *message*.

Comment: Do you mean the message divide into many packets is occur in Layer 4?